# Sed command and regular expressions

Tags: regex, sed, ubuntu-14.04

I need to change 'bind a.b.c.d:80' to 'bind x.b.f.d:80'. I wrote below command for this purpose but it is not working, i don't know why?

```
sed -i 's,bind *:35357,bind x.y.z.a:35357,' haproxy-sample.cfg
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that your example uses `35357` as port number and the text speaks of `80`. Please add some example input lines together with their corresponding required output lines.

Comment: Any time you are asking someone for help to debug a program telling them `it is not working` with no information about in what way it's not working (wrong output, no output, error message, something else?) is immensely frustrating and a waste of time for everyone involved. btw the problem is you are confusing `*`s meaning as a regexp metacharacter with as a globbing character.

Comment: @ Lars Fischer if you focus on my question, :80 or :35357 doesn't matter. What matter is the regex to update the changes in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executed from bash

```
$ echo bind 12.54.36.165:35357 | sed "s/bind [^:]\+:35357/bind a.y.z.a:35357/"
bind a.y.z.a:35357
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need somethink like this:

```
sed -r 's/^(bind\s+)([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.:]+)(:80(\s+.*)?)$/\1x.\3.f.\5\6/g' haproxy-sample.cfg
```

where you have to replace the literal `.f.` and `x.` with your required strings ( in the second part of the `sed s`).

It capture the various parts (`bind`, the four numbers of the address, the `:80` up to lineend into `\1` to `\6` and recombine the captured strings with the `b` and `f` .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your pattern contains a lone `*` -- you're probably thinking about shell globbing patterns where `*` matches 0 or more of any characters. sed does not speak shell patterns, it speaks regular expressions.
Where you have just `*`, you need `.*` -- in a regular expression the `.` character is a wildcard that matches any one character, and `*` is a *quantifier* that matches zero or more of the preceding thing.

```
sed -i 's/\(bind \).*\(:35357\)/\1x.y.z.a\2/'
```